# nginx open 443 port but can't access it

Tags: nginx, firewall, iredmail

I have a server was running fine with port 443, but not it's not running.

server is:
Contabo VPS, Ubuntu 22.04

contain nginx, iRedMail

using command `sof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN`, i get:

```
nginx     3124            root    6u  IPv4  39437      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     3124            root    7u  IPv4  39438      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     3125        www-data    6u  IPv4  39437      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
nginx     3125        www-data    7u  IPv4  39438      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

and `ufw status` return `inactive`

checking from client side with command `nmap -P0 mydomain.com`

```
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-12-11 09:17 EET
Nmap scan report for mydomain.com (IP Address)
Host is up (0.069s latency).
rDNS record for IP ADDRESS: ***********
Not shown: 991 filtered ports
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp  open   ssh
80/tcp  open   http
110/tcp closed pop3
143/tcp closed imap
443/tcp closed https
465/tcp closed smtps
587/tcp closed submission
993/tcp closed imaps
995/tcp closed pop3s

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 5.77 seconds
```

when I restart any service like `dovecot` I face this issue, after 2 or 3 hours the issue disappeared.

Comment: Any errors in the logs? What does `nginx -T` say?